# Invalid escape in identifier php

Tags: javascript, php

I have the below PHP code to generate a table that has a click-able image embedded in one of the columns. I know that the function works because if just `sortleads()` is called on click, the JavaScript function is properly called. I attempted to escape the single quotes around `?sort=IDD` but I get the following error `SyntaxError: Invalid escape in identifier: '\'` in my JavaScript console. I've also tried double backslashing to escape the backslashes but that gives a similar error. How should I properly escape the single quotes? I've also included all relevant code.

**Relevant PHP excerpt:**

```
$display_string .= "<th>ID <img src='img/down.png' alt='down arrow' 
onclick= 'sortLeads(\'?sort=IDD\')' height='50px' width='50px'> </th>";
```

**Full PHP:**

```
$display_string = "<table class='table table-bordered table-hover scroller'>";
$display_string .= "<thead class='thead-inverse'>";
$display_string .= "<tr>";
$display_string .= "<th>ID <img src='img/down.png' alt='down arrow' onclick= 'sortLeads(\'?sort=IDD\')' height='50px' width='50px'>
</th>";
display_string .= "</tr>";
$display_string .= "</thead>";
$display_string .= "<tbody>";
```

**Javascript:**

```
<script language="javascript" type = "text/javascript">
function sortLeads(query) 
{
    var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
    request.onreadystatechange = function()
    {
        if (request.readyState == 4)
        {
            var results = document.getElementById('sortLeads');
            results.innerHTML = request.responseText;
        }
    }
    request.open("GET", "sortLeads.php"+query, true);
    request.send(null);
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a syntax error in your PHP

**change**

```
$display_string .= "<th>ID <img src='img/down.png' alt = 'down arrow' onclick= 'sortLeads(\'?sort=IDD\')' height = '50px' width = '50px'>
</th>";display_string .= "</tr>";
```

**to**

```
$display_string .= "<th>ID <img src='img/down.png' alt='down arrow' onclick=\"sortLeads('?sort=IDD')\" height='50px' width='50px'></th>";
$display_string .= "</tr>";
```

Comment: Thanks that worked perfectly but I'm still confused as to why I should use escaped double quotes instead of escaped single quotes. Won't the escaped double quotes interfere with the original enclosing double quotes?

Comment: I'm glad it helped. You are escaping single quotes that are really not escaping at all so you end up printing sortLeads(\'?sort=IDD\') which lead to error. Plus you were having missing $ before your next concatenated variable.

Comment: @manpozi, Because you only escape the kind you used on the outside. `$x = "I said to him \"yo\".";` or `$x = 'I said to him \'yo\'.';`  You don't escape the other kind inside the other kind.

Comment: @manpozi, or better example: `$x = "I said to O'brien \"yo\".";` vs  `$x = 'I said to O\'brien "yo".';`

Comment: That makes a lot of sense. Thanks for the example @developerwjk and thanks for the help, Zayn!

Comment: You could probably have found a way to pass the escaped single quote but my preference would have been to do similar to Zayn. In fact, for consistency, I would generally try to ensure my HTML tag attributes all used double quotes (escaping where necessary - as in this example) to allow for passing single quoted strings to javascript etc.